# Keyword not supported data source, Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, connection

I know there are a bunch of questions like this on here, but I really cannot figure out how this is not a valid entity conn string.

```
metadata=res://*/PLCDB.csdl|res://*/PLCDB.ssdl|res://*/PLCDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

I am passing this conn string using

```
myPLCDBEntities.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connstring
```

As far as I know this is for sure a valid entity conn string as the format matches every other entity conn string I have ever had.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just so everyone is aware I have also tried removed the &quot and changing the entityclient to sqlclient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you don't need to pass the meta data at all when you pass the conn string in this fashion.